# How to find number of multiple line block comments using grep?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to find number of block comments that span across multiple lines in /usr/include/stdio.h

I managed to do it using 2 grep commands:

```
egrep '/\*' /usr/include/stdio.h | egrep -cv '\*/'
```

Can this be done in a more elegant way, using only one regex expression?

Comment: If you have `grep` with PCRE support, you can use a negative lookahead to match `/*` that isn't followed by `*/`.

Comment: But can it be done with only extended regex?

Comment: Doing negative lookahead with extended RE is hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is with negative lookahead, if PCRE is supported in your version of `grep` (e.g. GNU grep).

```
grep -P '/\*(?!.*\*/)' filename
```

Doing negative lookahead in general is difficult with just extended RE. The following comes close, but doesn't work if the single-line comment ends with `**/`.

```
grep -E '/\*[^*]*((\*($|[^/]))?[^*]*)*$'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/9g6RhQ/1)

Comment: This doesn't work if we have two '*' inside the comment.
For example `/* this is a * multiline * comment` (I'm talking about the RE expression, your PCRE example works)

Comment: I fixed it to repeat the last part with `(...)*`

Comment: Still doesn't work for `/* this is a multline comment *  asdfasdf **/`

Comment: I told you it's difficult to do negative lookahead.

Comment: There's probably some way to do it, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Can you remove the second part of your answer so I can accept it? I don't want to accept it now because the second part is not correct in all cases.

Comment: I've added text pointing out the limitation. I'm leaving it in in case it inspires someone to post the correction.